# I upload a file to AWS S3 bucket but cannot retrieve a public url to view through the browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I have an express app need to have an endpoint that receives an image from React, then I must upload it to an Amazon S3 bucket.

So far, I am testing as follows:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

app.post('/file-upload', (req, res, next) => {
    // Read content from the file
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filepath);

    // Setting up S3 upload parameters
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: filepath,
        Body: fileContent,
        ACL: "public-read"
    };
    s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`);
    });
})
```

When I hit the request, I can confirm the image in the bucket. However, a few things are still unclear.

1. How do I upload the file and retrieve the public URL? Right now the link I retrieve is actually downloading the image
2. I realized that I am using read file sync. However, how will I read if the file is to come via a request body?

Comment: The public URL would be in the format `https://BUCKET-NAME.s3.REGION-CODE.amazonaws.com/KEY`. For example, `https://puppy-pics.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/puppy1.png`

Answer (score 0):

To get a `resigned_url` of your file you have to use the function `get_pressigned_url` with the bucket name and the `object_key` of your file. Then, if you want to read the file you have to download the file from s3. I don't know is called the function in javascript but in python

```js
// get presigned url
function getPresignedUrl(bucketName, fileName, expirySeconds) {
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: fileName,
    Expires: expirySeconds
  };
  return s3.getSignedUrlPromise('getObject', params);
}
    
// download s3 file and read content from a presigned_url
async function downloadFileFromS3(presignedUrl) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('download.txt');
    const req = https.get(presignedUrl, (res) => {
      res.pipe(fileStream);
      fileStream.on('finish', () => {
        fileStream.close();
        const fileContent = fs.readFileSync('download.txt', 'utf8');
        fs.unlinkSync('download.txt');
        resolve(fileContent);
      });
    });
    req.on('error', (err) =>
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}
   
//download an s3 file with the object key
function downloadS3Object(bucketName, objectKey, destinationPath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(destinationPath);
    const params = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: objectKey,
    };
    
    const request = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
    request.on('error', (error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
    request.pipe(fileStream);
    fileStream.on('finish', () => {
      fileStream.close();
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: am a bit confused about how to incorporate your answer within my code. Any chance you can alter yours by including the upload?